# Aligning label controls differently within panel in WinForms

Tags: winforms, alignment, panel

I have a WinForms panel that holds two items, eg. labels.

I need to align them horizontally differently, let's say Label1 needs to be aligned to center of panel and Label2 needs to be aligned to the right side of the panel. The alignment have to preserved on resizing.

What panel should I use? Panel? FlowLayoutPanel? Anything else?
How should I set properties of panel/labels to achieve the above arrangement?

Comment: It's better to share an image before resizing and and image after resizing, then the requirement would be more clear. Maybe it's just some property settings using `Anchor`, maybe you need some event handling code.

Comment: Label can do it by itself without needing help from the panel.  Use its Anchor property.  Use Top + Right to get it to stay aligned to the right.  Center is a bit more work: use AutoSize = False, TextAlign = TopCenter, position the label in the center, Anchor = Left + Top + Right.

Comment: @Hans Passant: it works almost as i need. Your instruction "position the label in the center" is enough only if resizing means increasing the width. For a working solution on decreasing the width "position the label in the center" needs to be replaced to "stretch the width of the label to the edges of enclosing panel (and yes, do the stretching of right side through label2)". In the latter case one must care of the z orders as well to avoid hiding label2.

Answer (score 0):

Use `TabelLayoutPanel` with two columns. Set the left Label Anchor to Top and Bottom and label Text align center.
Label 2 anchor Right, Text Right Center.

Make `TabelLayoutPanel` either Dock to fill (if its the only control on the form) OR set the anchor to the sides that you would like to expand towards.

Further alignment of label can be controlled with its anchor positions within parent container and text alignment.

Comment: Edit: thank you, but as far as i see this will align Label1 to the center of column 1 of TableLayoutPanel, not to the center of the full width of entire TableLayoutPanel.